# How can I determine height and width for relatively recent versions of IE (was, what does IE8 not like about setting this style from JavaScript?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

```
var height = (library.window_dimensions().height - 200) + 'px';
document.getElementById('activity-feed').style.height = height;
```

IE8 reports an error with the second of these two lines. (The function returning a height and width returns integers for the window's height and width.)

What is IE complaining about?

--EDIT--

I was going off code at http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow that accommodates IE4 but perhaps not recent versions of IE; I'd just expected that someone thorough enough to address IE4 would make sense for common versions of IE. **The code was returning 0 for the window height, and the next line was complaining that it was given a height of -200px.**

The code given is:

```
function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
  window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

So, my next question: without necessarily reaching back past IE6, how do I determine width and height so that e.g. IE8 gets the right height?

Comment: Does `getElementById` return `null`?

Comment: setting the height this way should work just fine in IE8. You the error must be elsewhere, e.g. if your getElement does not return any element.

Comment: when you debug, what is `var height = (library.window_dimensions().height - 200) + 'px';` value?

Answer (score 2):

most likely, you are not reaching the element. The document.getElementByID() is a funky function. You are trying to set height on a null/undefined.